# Blue artifacts on multiple DP to DVI-D adapters, 1440p

Tags: dvi, displayport

I just bought a new RTX 3080 GPU, which has 3x DP 1.4a and 1x HDMI 2.x.

My 32" Samsung monitor has a DVI-D port I have been using at native 2560x1440@60Hz for many years on my older GPU (an AMD RX470) which HAD a DVI-D port (so it was DVI-D to DVI-D before).

So far I have tried 2 different "active" DP to DVI-D adapters, but both have the same problem -- blue "snow" and lines and other artifacts. I've tried multiple ports on the new GPU.

1. https://smile.amazon.com/3D-CAC-1010-DisplayPort-Dual-Link-Adapter/dp/B07T16LLB8/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_product_top?ie=UTF8
2. https://www.monoprice.com/product?p_id=12784&gclid=Cj0KCQjwxIOXBhCrARIsAL1QFCY6in6DEmqJZrIOs73eMTJHMkvX-uFc_m94_UjMZ06YMBdRMbcN8KgaAoduEALw_wcB

I'm using a 15 foot (~3m) shielded DVI-D cable which has worked flawlessly on my old GPU.

Am I just getting faulty adapters or is this blue artifact problem always going to be there with the DVI-D port on my monitor?

Running at 1080p instead of 1440p removes the blue interference, but that's not native resolution.

I also tested HDMI to HDMI directly from my GPU to my monitor (monitor has 1x HDMI, 1x DP IN USE, and 1x DVI-D) and I got 1440p without any artifacts, also at 15 foot cable.

Comment: If you can use HDMI directly -and- there's nothing in the monitor's specifications that require DP for optimal/maximum performance (there isn't, anything you can do with DP you can do exactly the same with HDMI in that monitor), why not just use THAT instead of dodgy adapters?

Comment: I do have HDMI, DP, and DVI-D on the monitor. However, HDMI and DP are spoken for by my HDMI matrix -> HDMI, and Mac Mini 2014 (Thunderbolt 2) to DisplayPort. Maybe the Mac Mini TB2 port can natively go to DVI-D at 1440p?

Comment: This might work for my Mac Mini: https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/mini-displayport-to-dual-link-dvi-d-active-adapter-m-f/apd/a7102181/pc-accessories?gacd=9694607-1003-5761040-266790354-0&dgc=st&ds_rl=1285903&gclid=Cj0KCQjwxIOXBhCrARIsAL1QFCZrGktw3c-mmIHEMtWggtAQNusTa7tfdmObpIzLmpD63CLQNJvbiQoaAgnREALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds&nclid=7UpUCp6V1qQiGr5UvkKrhka1hheGZN6MytKwvl5NdqpBpPEJIA7BTS0BVNzx6-3l

Answer (score 0):

you need an active dvi-d adapter to displayport that can support resolutions above 1080p typically costs around 50-100$

Comment: Or, to put it in concrete terms: It needs to support Dual-link DVI. A DP-to-HDMI adapter with a DVI connector tacked on isn’t going to cut it.